# First input not inserting into List

Tags: python

I am writing a program to accept user input to build a sentence word-by-word. After the user is done it is supposed to display the the sentence and the amount of words in the list. I know my code isn't complete and I am only requesting help for one issue. As of the moment I cannot get the first input to append or insert into the list, while others are. Any help would be great. I have been searching for awhile with no progress.

Code:

```
index = 0
def main():
    wordList = []
    inputFunc(wordList = [])

def inputFunc(wordList = []):
    global index
    print("To make a sentence, enter one word at a time... ")
    wordInput = input("Enter word... : ")
    wordList.insert(index,wordInput)
    index += 1
    choice = input("(y = Yes, n = No, r = Reset List)Another word?: " )

    inputCalc(choice)
    completeList(wordList)


def inputCalc(choice):
    while choice == 'y':
        inputFunc()
    while choice == 'n':
        return
    while choice == 'r':
        clearList()

def completeList(wordList):
    print(wordList)
    exit()




def clearList():
    wordList.clear()
    main()

main()
```

Comment: You seem to be generally confused about how functions work and how calling them works. It would be better to re-read whatever material you've been using to learn the language from, or better yet show us where you've been learning from so we can clarify anything that might be confusing you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have been using the book Staring out with Python 3rd Edition. This is for a class. I think you might be right about the functions. I will definitely have to go back over that chapter and re-read how functions operate. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of issues with your code, but the main reason why your word is not being appended to your list is because mutable default arguments don't generally do what you want.

Instead just perform everything in a single function.

```
def main():
    inputFunc()

def inputFunc():
    running = True
    wordList = []

    while running:
        print("To make a sentence, enter one word at a time... ")
        wordInput = input("Enter word... : ")
        wordList.append(wordInput)

        while True:
            choice = input("(y = Yes, n = No, r = Reset List)Another word?: " )
            if choice == 'y':
                break
            elif choice == 'n':
                running = False
                break
            elif choice == 'r':
                wordList = []
                break

    print(wordList)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The detailed answer is The first time you call `inputFunc()` inside `main()` you pass an empty list:

```
def main():
    wordList = []
    inputFunc(wordList=[])
```

When you call it again via recursion inside `inputCalc(choice)` you call `inputFunc()` without passing any arguments thus using a different list, the pre-initialized list.

```
def inputCalc(choice):
    while choice == 'y':
        inputFunc()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see now that I made this much more complicated than it needed to be. The boolean loop will be a bigger improvement. I was a bit confused on the `if_name_ == "_main_":` as I have not seen this used yet. A quick search led me to take a bit of understanding: Apparently the interpreter assigns variables to modules so as to determine which module is the main source? Is this in good practice to use even with a single module?

Comment: It allows you to import your script as a module without the main part executing. That lets you write things that are both reusable modules and standalone scripts. Its good practice and a simple additional.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!